# SharePoint List Form Textfield to a dropdown

Tags: forms, list, sharepoint

I've found a video from [SharePointTech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf9eXaDS8to) that explains how to change a textfield to a dropdown list on a List Form using data from open API. I'm trying to recreate it, but I'm hitting a roadblock with the new SharePoint Online. Instead of using "Country/Region", I created a new custom list with Company_Name. I took the person's code and made little changes that made a reference to "WorkCountry". When I save the changes (stop editing), the changes do not reflect and I get the same textfield. I had to use SharePoint Designer 2013 to create a new TestNewForm for new entry. Has anyone been able to reproduce this in SharePoint 2013 Designer? If so, would you be able an example?

Comment: Consider providing some code. People are not likely to watch the video. Just distill what you were doing into your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery's ajax method.

Updated code for your reference(you need to change the list name to your list name,InternalName is also):

```
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var demo = window.demo || {};
demo.nodeTypes = {
    commentNode: 8
};
demo.fetchCountries = function ($j) {
$.ajax({      
      url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Company_Name')/items",
      type: "get",
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },         
      success: function (data) {
        $j('table.ms-formtable td.ms-formbody').contents().filter(function () {
            return (this.nodeType == demo.nodeTypes.commentNode);
        }).each(function (idx, node) {
            if (node.nodeValue.match(/FieldInternalName="Country_x002f_Region"/)) {

                // Find existing text field (<input> tag)
                var inputTag = $(this).parent().find('input');

                // Create <select> tag out of retrieved countries
                var optionMarkup = '<option value="">Choose one...</option>';
                $j.each(data.d.results, function (idx, company) {
                    optionMarkup += '<option>' + company.Title + '</option>';
                });
                var selectTag = $j('<select>' + optionMarkup + '</select>');

                // Initialize value of <select> tag from value of <input>
                selectTag.val(inputTag.val());

                // Wire up event handlers to keep <select> and <input> tags in sync
                inputTag.on('change', function () {
                    selectTag.val(inputTag.val());
                });
                selectTag.on('change', function () {
                    inputTag.val(selectTag.val());
                });

                // Add <select> tag to form and hide <input> tag
                inputTag.hide();
                inputTag.after(selectTag);
            }
        });
    },
      error: function (data) {
                  console.log(data)
      }
    });
                }
                if (window.jQuery) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        (function ($j) {
            demo.fetchCountries($j);
        })(jQuery);
    });
}
</script>
```

My source list:

[image]

Test result:
[image]

Updated:

```
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var demo = window.demo || {};
demo.nodeTypes = {
    commentNode: 8
};
demo.fetchCountries = function ($j) {
$.ajax({      
      url: 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all',
      type: "get",
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },         
      success: function (data) {
        $j('table.ms-formtable td.ms-formbody').contents().filter(function () {
            return (this.nodeType == demo.nodeTypes.commentNode);
        }).each(function (idx, node) {
            if (node.nodeValue.match(/FieldInternalName="Country_x002f_Region"/)) {

                // Find existing text field (<input> tag)
                var inputTag = $(this).parent().find('input');

                // Create <select> tag out of retrieved countries
                var optionMarkup = '<option value="">Choose one...</option>';
                $j.each(data, function (idx, company) {
                    optionMarkup += '<option>' + company.name + '</option>';
                });
                var selectTag = $j('<select>' + optionMarkup + '</select>');

                // Initialize value of <select> tag from value of <input>
                selectTag.val(inputTag.val());

                // Wire up event handlers to keep <select> and <input> tags in sync
                inputTag.on('change', function () {
                    selectTag.val(inputTag.val());
                });
                selectTag.on('change', function () {
                    inputTag.val(selectTag.val());
                });

                // Add <select> tag to form and hide <input> tag
                inputTag.hide();
                inputTag.after(selectTag);
            }
        });
    },
      error: function (data) {
                  console.log(data)
      }
    });
                }
                if (window.jQuery) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        (function ($j) {
            demo.fetchCountries($j);
        })(jQuery);
    });
}
</script>
```

The difference in API will not have a great effect, the key is here '$ j.each (data, function (idx, company) {'. The structure of the return value of different APIs are different, you need to find useful data in return value.

Comment: Are you grabbing the data from another list or from another API outside of SharePoint?  The video showing that the api is https://restcountries.eu/... .

Comment: I created a source list(Company_name) in my SharePoint,and I use rest API to get list values.

Comment: Couldn't you have used the "LookUp" field type for the column which would grab the information from a different list with your SharePoint Site.  I've played around with the "LookUp" field type and it appears to function similar to what you're doing.  Rather than re-invent the data, I'm trying to grab the data from an OPEN API for SharePoint with no success.  I know that the video is five years old, but is it possible to do now, without having to use Microsoft Flows or PowerApps?

Comment: Provide me the OPEN API you tested.